# Coverting MySQl 'YYYY-MM-DD' to .Net DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

How can I read Default Mysql Date 'YYYY-MM-DD' using Datareader and convert it into .Net c# DatetimePicker.

In Short I want to see my date entered into MySQL visually selected on Datetimepicker.
ie Input from Mysql Default Date and Output on DateTimePicker on my Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read it as a string at all. Use the [`GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime.aspx) method on the reader to read it as a `DateTime`, and then you can specify that as the value of the `DateTimePicker`. It's worth avoiding string conversions wherever possible, in my opinion - they cause a lot of problems.